# Копирование и перемещение элементов списка инициализации

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << 1; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << 2; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout << 3; }
};

void foo(auto l) {}

int main() {
    auto l = {A{}};
    foo(l);
    foo(std::move(l));
}
```

Почему программа печатает `1`, а не `123` или другую комбинацию? Какие конструкторы вызываются и почему?

Comment: а каким компилятором это компилируется? использовать auto как тип параметра нужно очень осторожно. clang отказывается такое переваривать.

Comment: @KoVadim последними `gcc` и `clang`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если закрыть глаза на то, что clang не компилирует, а gcc - да, но с ворнингами, то на самом деле можно считать, что функция foo выглядит так

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T l) {}
```

(мы же знаем, что в большинстве случаев для auto способ вывода типов подобен шаблонному, поэтому, такая замена допустима).

Осталось выяснить, а какой же тип у `l`? А тут не все так очевидно. Он там `std::initializer_list<A>`. И при инициализации единственного его аргумента и вызывается конструктор по умолчанию.

Теперь можно понять и настоящую сигнатуру функции foo

```
void foo<std::initializer_list<A> >(std::initializer_list<A>)
```

(взято с недр ассемблерного кода, который сгенерировал gcc) и эта сигнатура соответствует тому, что и ожидалось вначале.

Теперь смотрим в документацию https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

> Initializer lists may be implemented as a pair of pointers or pointer and length. Copying a std::initializer_list **does not copy** the underlying objects.

и выделенное будет ответом.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bdPs16711 компилируется нормально с 20 стандартом

Comment: А что с перемещением?

Comment: у этого класса нет конструкторов перемещения. А раз нет, будет вызываться конструктор копирования. А его поведение уже известно.

Comment: почему конструктор копирования есть, а перемещения - нет?

Comment: initializer_list - это особый класс. Если Вы попробуете сделать его "вручную", то ничего не получится. Часть функций этого класса "реализованы внутри компилятора". Но так как внутренности этого класса - дело компилятора, то он все делает сам. Если почитать цитату с ответа, то там сказано, что там может быть указатель+размер. А даже в этом случае move конструктор будет максимум копировать указатель-длину, но не будет трогать вложенный (то есть `A`) класс

Comment: судя по документации, у листа есть только пустой конструктор

Comment: да. А если конструктор копирования явно не запрещен, то он будет сгенерирован.

Comment: тогда и конструктор перемещения будет

Comment: возможно. но это не важно. Он просто скопирует пару чисел. И все. я проверил, да, компилятор сгенерирует для него move конструктор